# Excel 2013 - using boolean logical functions

Tags: excel, boolean-logic, truthtable

[click here for the image of my excel worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKIWq.png) What is the formula for cell K3 (p=>q) => (p=>~q) . My goal is False, True, True, True. But i don't know the formula for it on excel. i've tried this formula =or(not(OR(NOT(B3);C3);OR(NOT(B3);NOT(C3))) , but it said "you,ve entered too many arguments for this function.

NOTE :

Please only using AND, OR, NOT function.

p=>q is equivalent to ~pvq

p<=>q is equivalent to (p=>q)^(q=>p) is equivalent to (~pvq)^(~qvp)

~ = negation

=> =  conditional "if-then"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If p is stored in A1 and q is in A2 then the formula in A3 will be

```
=NOT(AND(A1,A2))
```

Comment: Also, from De Morgan's laws (and at the expense of using 3 functions rather than 2) `=OR(NOT(A1),NOT(A2))`